# MySQL: get all articles to an order (2 tables)

Tags: php, mysql

**I have two tables:**

1. oxorders(oxid, oxbillfname, oxbilllname, oxordernr)
2. oxorderarticles(oxid, oxorderid, oxtitle, oxamount, oxartnum)

Now I want to output each order, including the corresponding articles.

actually it should be enough if I do output all orders in a while and inside this while i do another selection on the oxorderarticles with the matching article / orderid.

The code is shortended. The mysqli connection is established and working.

The final goal ist to render the result as html for an email.

Order Nr: xxx
Articles: 
Article 1 | amount | shop link
Article 2 | amount | shop link

and so on..

**Like that:**

```
<?php
/**
 * List all orders with corresponding articles
 * @return array
*/
private function getOrderlist(){

    $orders = array();
    $theOrder = array();
    $theOrderArticles = array();

    // Order List - All orders
    $sql_order = "
            SELECT
              oxorder.*,
              CASE 
                WHEN LCASE(OXBILLSAL) = 'mr' OR LCASE(OXBILLSAL) = 'herr' THEN 'Sehr geehrter Herr'
                WHEN LCASE(OXBILLSAL) = 'mrs' OR LCASE(OXBILLSAL) = 'frau' THEN 'Sehr geehrte Frau'
              ELSE 'Sehr geehrte Damen und Herren'
              END as 'order_anrede'

            FROM oxorder

            WHERE
              DATEDIFF(oxorder.OXSENDDATE,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) < 7 AND
              oxorder.OXSENDDATE != '0000-00-00 00:00:00' AND
              oxorder.OXORDERDATE > '2015-01-01 00:00:00' AND
            ";

    // Executing
    try{
        $result_order = $this->_dbCon->query($sql_order);

        // Fetching the articles of an order
        while($row_order = $result_order->fetch_assoc()){
            $sql_order_articles = "
              SELECT 
              concat(oxoa.OXTITLE) as title,
              oxoa.*

              FROM oxorderarticles oxoa, oxseo seo

              WHERE 
                oxoa.OXORDERID = '".$row_order['OXID']."' AND
                oxoa.OXARTID = seo.OXOBJECTID";

            $result_order_articles = $this->_dbCon->query($sql_order_articles);

            while($row_order_articles = $result_order_articles->fetch_assoc()){
                $theOrderArticles[] = $row_order_articles;
            }

            $theOrder['OXID'] = $row_order['OXID'];
            // Writing the articles array into the article field
            $theOrder['articles'] = $theOrderArticles;
        }

    } catch(Exception $e){
        echo $e;
    }
    return $theOrder;
}
```

The result should be an array, containing all orders (including each corresponding articles).

I always get the error: **Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch_assoc() on a non-object**. After max. execution time, or if I cancel the process.

I tried it on many ways now. Using an extra function (getOrderArticles, which returns the article array). Every function is working fine separately, but if I use getOrderArticles inside the while of the getOrders, the same thing happens.
I also checked the SQL-Code manually. It works. But not in the functions (with the articles).

Comment: Why not use one query, instead of two?

Comment: I tried it with a subselect, but it made no sense to me.. because I have about 25.000 results which I have to go through. Or what do you mean?

Comment: Because you're declaring the query outside the loop, when the $row-variable isn't available? I use PDO (where such things are perfectly fine to do), not mysqli_, but that seems the most likely reason.

Comment: oh, no that's not the problem. Actually I am declaring it inside the loop. It was a mistake in the post.

Comment: @Strawberry tried it with LEFT, RIGHT and INNER JOIN on the id. Does not work for me. It combines the tables, ok.. but I do not get all articles.

Comment: does orderarticles(id, name, amount, artnr) have an orderid field?  orderarticles(id, name, amount, artnr, orderid) ?

Comment: Ok. See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: @WEBjuju yes. I tried to join it on order.id = articles.orderid but I do not get all articles, just one. And lot's of NULL fields.

Comment: gothca, well, the code up there shows why that would happen...i see your comment about the posting, but can you be sure we're looking at the right code, please?  there is a serious flaw in what's there that would definitely cause what you are seeing.

Comment: @WEBjuju: Updated the example code with the actual code.

Comment: ok, the problem is no the code. It's the execution time.. the result is about 4000 datasets. And for each order, I have to check for the articles.

Comment: yes, but even so, it shouldn't take long.  be sure you have keys/indexes on the columns that relate the tables together, for instance oxoa.OXORDERID , oxoa.OXARTID, and seo.OXOBJECTID all need to have indexes on them.

Comment: sorry, what was your question?

Comment: What is the `COLLATION` of `OXBILLSAL`?  If it is one of the `..._ci` collations, then don't bother calling `LCASE()`.

Answer (score 0):

Those errors...  It sounds like one of those `$this->_dbCon->query(...)` is faiing, but not being caught.

In particular, I don't think you can do

```
SELECT ..., oxoa.* FROM...
```

Either spell out the columns you want, or move `oxoa.*` to the start.